# Google Sheets go to specified filter view On Open

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have filter views that are named with user id's (email id).  When a user opens my sheet, I would like to run an onOpen script that opens that existing filter view.

I understand that I will need to use API, but, I have searched but cannot find anything to get started, namely how to call / open an existing filter view.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You will likely have an issue with script identity permissions as well, unless you are in gsuite and the users are in your domain.

Comment: Great points..I am in gsuite and only users in our domain will be accessing.